# json data fields and php json functions

Tags: php, mysql, json

Seems I cannot use JSON inside MYSQL tables - there is no such an option when choosing data type for a field - `phpMyAdmin ver 4.8.3`.

Question - if I use php functions `json_encode` and `json_decode` to get and set values inside `varchar` or `text` field - do I need JSON fields at all?

Comment: It kind of depends if you want to query things inside the json. If so you might want to consider something like MongoDB. If the format of the json is pretty standard (one level deep, usually same keys), you could just extrapolate those fields into mysql columns. If you won't ever need to query the data, you can just use json_encode/decode and stick it in a varchar or text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you do, unless you don't want to perform searches on the key-values of those json strings. MySQL Json Type allows you to do that, apart from storing the json in an efficient way.

You could use a blob or a text  type. Varchar is too short for a json, unless you have jsons that are less than 255 chars long.

A blob could be a good idea. You can map that to a resource in php (not loading the whole file into memory) and then use a json stream parser [like this one](https://packagist.org/packages/halaxa/json-machine) to read the contents of your file.

But again, **storing a json as a string will not allow you to query in an efficient way using your json data**.

> NOTE: Mysql supports the Json Type from 5.7.8. PhpMyAdmin is another piece of software. If your json type is not there, is probably because of your MySQL version. Run `mysql -V` in your terminal to check.

Comment: if I select data as usual and run `json_decode` I'm getting an array and still able to search on key-value pairs, isnt' it?

Answer (score 0):

You can store you JSON Object as a string in a `string` field or you can use it in a field which hold data of JSON type

This is valide with MySQL version 8

**Advantage**

1. The Advantage with this type is that It perform automatic validation of JSON documents stored in JSON columns and invalid documents produce an error.
2. Optimized storage format. JSON documents stored in JSON columns are converted to an internal format that permits quick read access to document elements

You can read the entire documentation here [The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)

**The Cons**

If you choose to use a `VARCHAR` OR `TEXT` field to store you JSON data as a String, It's up to you to parse the Data correctly after you have retrieve It from the database for that to behave like a correct JSON object

Answer (score 0):

[As per the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

> As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type defined by RFC 7159 that enables efficient access to data in JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) documents.

Check your MySQL version to find out if it supports JSON datatype.

An answer to your question:

You can `json_encode` your data and store it in a `text` field. After retrieving it from the database table, do a`json_decode`.